# Getting value of Navigation property in join

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have generated the classes from the database using scaffold.

```
public partial class Class1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Class2ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Class1 = new HashSet<Class1>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Allotment { get; set; }
    public string Manual { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class1>Class1 {get; set;}
}
```

So there is a requirement to **join these two tables** in entity and get the data. And I am getting the result.

Here is my code:

```
var _class1Repo = UnitWork.GetGenericRepositoryFor<Class1>().AsNoTracking();

var _class2Repo = UnitWork.GetGenericRepositoryFor<Class2>().AsNoTracking();

var query = from _cls1 in _class1 in _class1Repo
            join _cls2 in _class2Repo on _cls1.Class2ID = _cls2.ID
            where _cls2.ID = 2
            select new Class1() {
                Name =_cls1 .Name,
                Address =_cls1.Address,
                City =_cls1 .City,
                Country =_cls1.Country
                // I want just only one property value inside this from class2
            };
```

I need to include Class2 one property. How can I do that? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: use `Class2.property = _cls2.property`.

Comment: I did that too but it doesn't show anything after Class2. no intelligence help comes up.

Comment: it because of you do not have constructor in `Class 1`. Simply define constructor so you can access the property.

Comment: It says "the name 'Class2' doesn't exist in the current context".

Comment: Ok. But tomorrow what If I want to update the class using scaffolding than do need to do same thing for each class.

Comment: you have to define empty constructor in all of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `Class1.cs` like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Class2ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Class2 Class2 { get; set; }

    public Class1() {}
    // Define this constructor
 }
```

A `constructor` is a special method of the class which gets automatically invoked whenever an instance of the class is created.

So whenever you created instance you can easy to access the property.

Comment: It means if there are 100 classes will be affected if there is any scaffold??

Comment: if you create the `constructor` is doesn't effect on your scanffold. it just give you instance to access it's property. and for basic need all class with default constuctor are there it's a structure of class.

Comment: so keep in mind whenever you are creating any class. just define the empty constuctor on it.

Comment: Ok!!! So I have created the empty constructor in calss1. But still, there is nothing  class2.nothing. Also, I have updated my code these classes are partial classes. I forget to mentioned that.

Comment: one more problem is there you have define `Class2` in `Class1` and you also define `Class1` List in `Class2`. are you sure your structure is this. that is looks like iteration classes.

Comment: Yes. Scaffold did this automatically. I have not made any changes manually except empty constructor.